# MODx Revo: Empty comboboxes on the Admin Panel

Tags: combobox, modx, modx-revolution

I just installed a copy of MODX Revolution 2.3.1-pl.
And everything is fine, but comboboxes are empty. I can see that combobox data comes with JSON/AJAX and JSON is correct. But anyway I cannot see a proper values on the combo box.

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found [the problem is](https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/issues/748) in unsupported experimental ES6 features (Chrome flag #enable-javascript-harmony) by the legacy ExtJS 3.X.

See also: [Comboboxes are ed up in Chrome](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?273501-Comboboxes-are-ed-up-in-Chrome&p=1010671)

Answer (score 0):

1. First create the imaevents.combo.js file here `modxcloud\assets\components\yourcomponentFolder\js\mgr\widgets` and add this code in `imaevents.combo.js`:

   ```
   Imaevents.combo.Event_status = function(config) {
       config = config || {};
       Ext.applyIf(config,{
           store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
               id: 0
               ,fields: ['event_status','display']
               ,data: [
                    ['','Event Status']
                   ,['Normal','Normal']
                   ,['Closed','Closed']
                   ,['Cancelled','Cancelled']
                   ,['Full','Full']
                   ,['Waiting list','Waiting list']
                 ]
           })
           ,mode: 'local'
           ,displayField: 'display'
           ,valueField: 'event_status'
       });
       Imaevents.combo.Event_status.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);
   };
   Ext.extend(Imaevents.combo.Event_status,MODx.combo.ComboBox);
   Ext.reg('imaevents-combo-event_status',Imaevents.combo.Event_status);
   ```
2. Use this combo box by calling the xtype "imaevents-combo-event_status"

   ```
   {
       xtype: 'imaevents-combo-event_status'
       ,fieldLabel: _('imaevents.event_status')
       ,name: 'event_status'
       ,anchor: '100%'
   }
   ```

Comment: No, this is custom created combo box So you can use this in your Component Folder.

And you can also create your own combo box following the same structure.

Comment: I mean in subject I deal with system comboboxes